# PDO::FETCH_OBJ argument in fetchAll() function

Tags: php, pdo

hey guys please tell me what does this argument mean in the PDO fetchAll function
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
I've looked it up in the manual but I've found nothing about it, I've got it from a tutorial but I dunno what it means

Comment: Can you post a code ?

Comment: if ($this->_query->execute()) {
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: It means that each row in the result array will be an object, just like calling `$stmt->fetchObject()`.

Comment: _I've looked it up in the manual_ No, you didn't look in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I've looked here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php and didn't find it, thanks

Comment: No, you didn't `fetch_style
Controls the contents of the returned array as documented in PDOStatement::fetch()`

Answer (score 5):

All PDO "fetch" methods, requests an optional parameter called `$fetch_style` that means the data structure which your entity will be returned, when you use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` it means that your entity will be an `stdClass` instance, if you use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` it will return an associative array with the entity data, for more information, check the link below:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Edit: The method `PDO::fetchAll()` will return an array with the entities found by your statement, so if you use the `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` you will access your entites like:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$result[0]->field;
```

If you use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetch style, you will access your entity using:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result[0]['property'];
```